# Recover data from deleted hard drive

Tags: data-recovery, windows-installation

I deleted one of the hard drives when I installed a fresh copy of Windows 7.

I want to recover the data from that drive – can I do that?

Comment: When you say you "deleted one of the hard driver when I installed the win7". What exactly did you do? What option did you choose? Was it `ERASE`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if anything got written over sectors with data in it, it'll likely be impossible to recover on a modern drive. Always recover to a different drive

There's a handful of recovery software i've used before with varying levels of success. I tend to run [recurva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) first - it does seem to have a good level of generalised recovery, and has a good, easy to understand UI.

Next i'll try [photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec), it tends to focus on specific filetypes, and 'carves' files, so it has a better chance of recovering those files. However it messes up filenames and [you need to sort through them](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/After_Using_PhotoRec)

Finally, the method i use when i haven't actually done anything other than formatting, [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), this should, if all goes well, undelete the old partition. I'd suggest doing the other two first so you have a better chance of having already recovered your old data should this fail.

And next time, don't forget to backup anything important!

Comment: thanxx I didn't find the solution, anyway I was able skip this part